# LibGDX - Box2D: move object without speed restriction using MouseJoint

Tags: box2d, libgdx, physics, game-engine

I am using MouseJoint for dragging objects. But the movement of objects is too slow.

[image]

I need to move them with the speed of mouse. Currently, I use these settings for `MouseJointDef`:

```
MouseJointDef def = new MouseJointDef();
def.bodyA = groundBody;
def.bodyB = hitBody;
def.collideConnected = true;
def.target.set(testPoint.x, testPoint.y);
def.maxForce = 10000.0f * hitBody.getMass();
def.frequencyHz=100;
def.dampingRatio=0;
```

and these one for body:

```
 Body box = world.createBody(def);
 MassData mass = new MassData();
 mass.mass=100;
 //mass.I=1; What is it???
 mass.center.set(width/2, height/2);
 box.setMassData(mass);
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your game width and height is too large like 800x480 or something then divide it by 40 like... 20x12 ....

this is because box2d speed is limited to 2 units. and what you want is more units per time step but your screen is too big to achieve that .. so if you shorten you world then the speed problem will be solved.

Comment: My mistake was I used `this.cam.setToOrtho(false, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());` after creating instance of camera with right parameters! :) Thanks